# Solve the ODe with five variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $$\frac{dx}{2p}=\frac{dy}{2q}=\frac{du}{2(p^2+q^2}=\frac{dp}{2up}=\frac{dq}{2uq}=dt$$

as functions $$x=x(t), y=y(t), u=u(t), p=p(t), q=q(t)$$

My method is use the last three equalities to deduce $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+u\frac{du}{dt}=0$$
But this nonlinearity troubles me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last line:

Consider $F = u^2$

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = 2 u \frac{du}{dt} $$

Thus suppose we re-arrange

$$ \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + u \frac{du}{dt} = 0 $$

Into

$$  \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} = - u \frac{du}{dt} $$

Then we can re-write it as

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{du}{dt} \right] =  \frac{d}{dt}\left[ - \frac{1}{2}u^2\right] $$

Thus we have

$$ \frac{du}{dt} = C_1-\frac{1}{2}u^2 $$

From here we will use the standard algorithm for solving linear ODEs

$$ \frac{1}{C_1 - \frac{1}{2}u^2} du  = 1 dt$$

Since the choice of C is arbitrary this can be re-written as

$$2 \frac{1}{C_1 - u^2} du  = 1 dt$$

We can integrate both sides:

$$2 \int \frac{1}{C_1 - u^2} du  = t + C_2$$

The left hand side can be attacked with Partial Fractions: We decompose the integrand into:

$$ \frac{1}{C_1 - u^2} = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{C_1} - u)(\sqrt{C_1} + u)} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{C_1} - u} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{C_1} + u}$$

We find the constants A,B

$$ B(\sqrt{C_1} - u) + A(\sqrt{C_1} + u) = 0 $$

Which (based on grouping like terms of $C_1$ and $u$ tells us

$$ \begin{pmatrix} Au - Bu = 0 \\ \sqrt{C_1}(A + B) = 1 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} A = B \\ (A + B) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1}} \end{pmatrix} $$

Giving us

$$ A = B = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{C_1}} $$

So our integral is now

$$2 \int \left[ \frac{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{C_1}}}{\sqrt{C_1} -u} + \frac{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{C_1}}}{\sqrt{C_1} + u} \right] du  $$

We factor the top parts giving us

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1}} \int \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1} -u} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1} + u}  \right] du $$

Which integrates to

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1}} \left( \ln(\sqrt{C_1} + u) - \ln(\sqrt{C_1} - u) \right) $$

So we have

$$2 \int \frac{1}{C_1 - u^2} du  = t + C_2$$

Gives rise to

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1}} \left( \ln(\sqrt{C_1} + u) - \ln(\sqrt{C_1} - u) \right)  = t + C_2$$

Which resolves to

$$ \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{C_1} + u}{\sqrt{C_1} - u} \right)   = C_1 t + C_2 $$

We exponentiate both sides to find

$$ \left( \frac{\sqrt{C_1} + u}{\sqrt{C_1} - u} \right) = C_2 e^{C_1t} $$

And now solve for $u$ as

$$ \sqrt{C_1} + u = (C_2 e^{C_1t})(\sqrt{C_1} - u) \rightarrow $$

$$\left(1 - C_2 e^{C_1t} \right)u= (C_2 e^{C_1t}-1)\sqrt{C_1} $$

$$ u = \frac{(C_2 e^{C_1t}-1)\sqrt{C_1}}{\left(1 - C_2 e^{C_1t} \right)} $$

### Alternate Trig Approach

$$ \int \frac{2}{C_1 - u^2} du = \frac{2}{\sqrt{C_1}} arctanh^{-1} \left( \frac{u}{\sqrt{C_1}} \right)  $$

So our solution then becomes

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{C_1}} arctanh^{-1} \left( \frac{u}{\sqrt{C_1}} \right) = t + C_2 $$

$$ arctanh^{-1} \left( \frac{u}{\sqrt{C_1}} \right) = C_1t + C_2$$

$$ u = \sqrt{C_1}tanh\left( C_1t + C_2\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you equation is this following
$$y''+yy'=0$$
let
$$y'=p\Longrightarrow y''=\dfrac{dp}{dx}=\dfrac{dp}{dy}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=p\dfrac{dp}{dy}$$
so
$$p\dfrac{dp}{dy}+yp=0$$
so
$$p(\dfrac{dp}{dy}+y)=0\Longrightarrow p=0,\text{or},\dfrac{dp}{dy}=-y$$
if 
$p=0\Longrightarrow y=C$

if $$\dfrac{dp}{dy}=-y\Longrightarrow p=-\dfrac{y^2}{2}+C$$
then
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{y^2}{2}+C$$
then it is easy it